# What is the best way to solve "Cannot return value referencing function parameter" with an async function?

Tags: rust, reference, borrowing

I am fighting with a borrowing issue:

```rust
async fn bugger(_foo: &String) {}

fn main() {
    Some("".to_string()).map(|foo| bugger(&foo));
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `foo`
 --> src/main.rs:4:36
  |
4 |     Some("".to_string()).map(|foo| bugger(&foo));
  |                                    ^^^^^^^----^
  |                                    |      |
  |                                    |      `foo` is borrowed here
  |                                    returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I guess the problem is that the future returned by `bugger()` stores the `&String` reference in its state machine.

Since the `foo` variable is owned in the `map()` closure, a workaround would be:

```rust
async fn bugger(_foo: &String) {}

async fn workaround(_foo: String) {
    bugger(&_foo).await
}

fn main() {
    Some("".to_string()).map(|foo| workaround(foo));
}
```

I find this inelegant because the compiler knows that `foo` is owned and used only in the call to `bugger`, so the `workaround()` function seems like avoidable boilerplate.

Assuming I cannot change the signature of `bugger()` (because it is defined in another crate), is there a better way to do this?

Note: using `.as_ref().map()` would also work for this contrived example, but I would like a solution which works in more complex cases as well (e.g. `map()` in the middle of an iterator or stream).

EDIT: here is a more realistic example to make the use case clearer.

```rust
use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt};

async fn bugger(_foo: & String) -> u8 { 0u8 }

fn main() {
    let vec = vec!["".to_string()];

    let _stream = stream::iter(vec)
        // Apply async function
        .map(|foo| bugger(&foo))
        // Process 10 items "in parallel"
        .buffer_unordered(10)
        // Possibly do more stuff with the stream here
        // [...]
        // .collect().await
        ;
}
```

Basically I want to apply a third-party async function (taking a reference) in a stream.

Comment: Can you give an example of where `as_ref` wouldn't work? It's exactly what you want for this since you want the borrow to last longer than the closure.

Comment: your use case don't make sense. if you borrow something it must live as long as you want borrow it. async is ... async so you can't return a async thing that borrow variable on the stack, if you want, the function that call `bugger` must borrow this variable too.

Comment: @Stargateur: I have edited the question to provide a more realistic example. I hope the use case makes more sense now.

Comment: In your new example, you can iterate over references into `vec`, rather than values with `stream::iter(&vec)`. Then there's no need to make a new borrow in the closure, fixing the problem. Just like the original example, the idea is to make sure the borrow lasts long enough.

Comment: Yes, but again this is an example. Imagine a longer stream with more steps before the map(), where at some point I have owned values. Or imagine that the stream is returned from a function, but the vector is local to the function.